# Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded only at second time

Tags: php, json

I am dealing with a problem where answer from url(in my case it is JSON file) that I use 2nd time is taking a while, so php returns me

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in [myfile] on line 54
```

Here is some code:

**save_road.php**

```
<?php    
include('simple_html_dom.php');
include('controller.php');
$restrictions = new road_restrictions; ?>
```

**controller.php**

```
include('functions-map.php');

class road_restrictions {

    function __construct() {
        $road_id = get_road_id();
        show($road_id);
        $informacion = $this->get_all_info($road_id);  //goes here

        foreach ($informacion as $info) {
            $this->save($info);
        }

        //show($informacion);
    }

    function get_all_info($road_id) {

        foreach ($road_id as $id) {
            $road_info = get_info($id);   //goes here

            if ($road_info !== NULL) {
                $info[] = $road_info;
            }
        }
        return $info;
    }

    function save($info) {
        save_road($info);
    }
}
```

**functions-map.php**

```
function get_info($id) {                
$json = file_get_contents('http://restrictions.eismoinfo.lt/');  //stuck here
$array = json_decode($json, true);
//other code
```

It just takes too much time at this point of the code. First time when it is being called **functions-map.php** function `get_road_id()` (where is the same code to get json) it works just fine, but when it comes to `get_info` function `file_get_contents` it just waits for something till time ends.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You can increase the max exec time with ini_set('max_execution_time', 180);(3 min.). But try to track the problem in the chrome console under network tab, to see if u have high TTFB or download time. If waiting is because of downloading, enable gzip compression.

Comment: I second Nikolay's comment, if this other server is yours, enabling GZIP compression on HTTP can make a huge difference, like up to 10:1 improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try increasing **max_execution_time** from php.ini file.

OR

add this line before executing your get_info(); function **set_time_limit(60);**